# Forma mais rápida de calcular a/b+c/d com float

Tags: desempenho, matemática, float

Pode-se operar quatro `floats` na fórmula `a/b+c/d` (duas divisões e uma soma) de maneira matematicamente equivalente com a fórmula `(a*d+b*c)/(b*d)` (três produtos, uma divisão e uma soma).

Sabe-se que mais instruções aumenta o número de arredondamentos (tendendo a aumentar erros) mas que as instruções de processador para o cálculo de divisão (entre `floats` sim, mas principalmente entre dois inteiros) custa muito mais em desempenho do que multiplicação.

Ainda assim, é difícil decidir entre os dois modos em termos de desempenho. O que é mais rápido? Uma divisão ou três produtos? Qual das duas fórmulas nas mais diversas linguagens tende a resultar em melhor desempenho?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É difícil e é fácil.

Universalmente é difícil porque cada arquitetura, incluindo as versões dela, podem fazer muita diferença. Não só isto, o compilador que está usando e opções ligadas podem fazer diferença, incluindo que podemos estar falando de linguagens diferentes.

Especificamente é fácil, se você quer saber em uma máquina específica qual é mais rápido é só testar os dois nela e ver qual executa mais rápido, não tem segredo. Ou quase não tem, porque precisa saber que a execução pode variar em algumas arquiteturas.

De fato a divisão custa caro, mas 3 multiplicações não costuma custar tão barato, triplamente **pode** demorar mais que uma divisão.

Há casos que pode não fazer diferença, os compiladores de linguagens que prezam pela performance tendem a decompor a expressão e tentar remontá-la de uma forma que seja mais rápida, então se fizer a divisão e o compilador puder provar que trocá-la por multiplicações fica mais rápido sem mudar o resultado ele o fará por você. Em linguagens que não se preocupam com performance isto não ocorre porque não é filosofia dela. Se o compilador não faz veja se pode usar outro.

O compilador pode até usar instruções vetoriais em alguns casos se ele entender que é possível e ajuda alguma coisa.

Se eu tiver que chutar eu acho que as multiplicações no lugar da divisão pode dar algum ganho, se o compilador não fizer esta otimização para você porque se fizer dá na mesma. Se não estiver usando C, C++ ou algo parecido duvido que fará muita diferença. Este tipo de otimização é das últimas que deve fazer, tem outras que dão melhores resultados, em alguns casos várias ordens de magnitude de diferença. E algumas linguagens nem dão muita chance de melhoria.

Mas tem outros fatores que podem influenciar na execução geral, e até mesmo na específica, afinal tem processadores que uma mesma instrução pode ter um custo diferente dependendo do caso de execução, ou seja, em cada execução pode dar um custo ligeiramente diferente. É muito complicado garantir o tempo. Dá para estabelecer uma faixa.

Só lembrando que só deve se preocupar com isso se for fazer muita diferença, for algo que ajuda demais, depois de medido, e deve saber que a situação pode mudar.

Hoje acesso à memória, e principalmente alocação, é muito mais importante para ganhar performance.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).